# UICollectionView inside a tableviewcell: scrollToIndex not working

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uitableview

I have created a simple UICollectionView inside of a tableviews, UITableviewCell. The collection view is set to scroll horizontally.  I am trying to scroll to a certain element within the collection view using scrollToIndex at:, I have placed the scroll request in the tableviewcell's layoutSubviews method. When the collection view is displayed, no scrolling takes place. 
Here is the tableviewcell's layoutSubviews code:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)

    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.left , animated: false)
}
```

It's quite simple, so really not sure why this is not working? 
Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I would suggest doing it somewhere that is _not_ related to `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Could you suggest where in UITableViewCell I could do that?

Comment: @Kitcc Try scrolling the collectionView in the cell's didMoveToWindow() ?